# OSX Lion Homebrew "brew install mysql -v" problems

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, installation, homebrew

I am working to install mysql locally using home brew and it keeps blowing up.  When I run brew doctor I do not get any errors, and the full verbose output of attempting to install mysql is https://gist.github.com/2424859, ending with:

```
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
Error: Failed executing: cmake . -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20 -DMYSQL_DATADIR=/usr/local/var/mysql -DINSTALL_MANDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/man -DINSTALL_DOCDIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/doc/mysql -DINSTALL_INFODIR=/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.20/share/info -DINSTALL_MYSQLSHAREDIR=share/mysql -DWITH_SSL=yes -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=utf8 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=utf8_general_ci -DSYSCONFDIR=/usr/local/etc -DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF -DWITH_READLINE=yes (mysql.rb:77)
These existing issues may help you:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/8063
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/9142
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11710
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11754
Otherwise, please report the bug:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/reporting-bugs
```

. I am running osx lion, full xcode 4.3.2.

any ideas on what the primary issue is?

Comment: Did you look at the related issues? Or do the things suggested in your first gist? FYI, it's better to post at least *some* of the information in your actual question.

Comment: yes, been researching this and trying things for the last hour.  still a noob to rails :(  been hacking through brew doctor now all fixed except: Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew's core.
Unless you know what you are doing, you should run:
  cd /usr/local && git reset --hard

Comment: yes. did not work, keeps coming back with the same message.  now I am trying to figure out how to get rid of it.  on and on and the wheel goes right?

Comment: @DaveNewton  I have finally been able to solve the brew doctor issues: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11761 any pointers on where to take this thread about mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after posting on the homebrew github issues:https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11762

here is how I fixed the issue:

```
cd /usr/local
brew uninstall cmake
git checkout 948c2769 Library/Formula/cmake.rb
brew install mysql
```