# homebrew brew doctor fail message

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am going through my home brew doctor messages and no matter what I do I can not seem to remove this message:

> Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew's core.
>
> Unless you know what you are doing, you should run:
>   `cd /usr/local && git reset --hard`

Does anyone have any idea on how to get rid of this?

From git status /usr/local

```
#   Library/Aliases/dwarffortress
#   Library/Aliases/ultima4
#   Library/Aliases/ultima7
#   Library/Contributions/examples/
#   Library/Formula/abfind.rb
#   Library/Formula/abuse.rb
#   Library/Formula/akonadi.rb
#   Library/Formula/angband.rb
#   Library/Formula/apc.rb
#   Library/Formula/aqua-less.rb
#   Library/Formula/argp-standalone.rb
#   Library/Formula/attica.rb
#   Library/Formula/bashreduce.rb
#   Library/Formula/c10t.rb
#   Library/Formula/chocolate-doom.rb
#   Library/Formula/cmigemo.rb
#   Library/Formula/coffee-script.rb
#   Library/Formula/csstidy.rb
#   Library/Formula/dosbox.rb
#   Library/Formula/dotless.rb
#   Library/Formula/dwarf-fortress.rb
#   Library/Formula/exult.rb
#   Library/Formula/flip.rb
#   Library/Formula/frobtads.rb
#   Library/Formula/frotz.rb
#   Library/Formula/gearman-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/gnu-chess.rb
#   Library/Formula/gnu-go.rb
#   Library/Formula/growlme.rb
#   Library/Formula/imagick.rb
#   Library/Formula/inform6.rb
#   Library/Formula/jnethack.rb
#   Library/Formula/jwhois.rb
#   Library/Formula/kde-phonon.rb
#   Library/Formula/kdebase-runtime.rb
#   Library/Formula/kdelibs.rb
#   Library/Formula/kdepimlibs.rb
#   Library/Formula/libgdiplus.rb
#   Library/Formula/libiconv.rb
#   Library/Formula/libsgml.rb
#   Library/Formula/maatkit.rb
#   Library/Formula/mcrypt-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/mednafen.rb
#   Library/Formula/memcache-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/memcached-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/memcachedb.rb
#   Library/Formula/midgard2-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/mongo-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/n2n.rb
#   Library/Formula/nazghul.rb
#   Library/Formula/nethack.rb
#   Library/Formula/netris.rb
#   Library/Formula/ninja.rb
#   Library/Formula/open-tyrian.rb
#   Library/Formula/orderly.rb
#   Library/Formula/oxygen-icons.rb
#   Library/Formula/parsley.rb
#   Library/Formula/pbrt.rb
#   Library/Formula/pcntl-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/phpmyadmin.rb
#   Library/Formula/pioneers.rb
#   Library/Formula/platypus.rb
#   Library/Formula/pspell-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/qimageblitz.rb
#   Library/Formula/robotfindskitten.rb
#   Library/Formula/shared-desktop-ontologies.rb
#   Library/Formula/shen.rb
#   Library/Formula/slashem.rb
#   Library/Formula/solr-php.rb
#   Library/Formula/soprano.rb
#   Library/Formula/sparse.rb
#   Library/Formula/spim.rb
#   Library/Formula/stone-soup.rb
#   Library/Formula/strigi.rb
#   Library/Formula/uggconv.rb
#   Library/Formula/unnethack.rb
#   Library/Formula/voldemort.rb
#   Library/Formula/woof.rb
#   Library/Formula/xboard.rb
#   Library/Formula/xcache.rb
#   Library/Formula/xdebug.rb
#   Library/Formula/xmoto.rb
#   Library/Formula/xu4.rb
#   Library/Homebrew/test/tests
```

Comment: Doesn't it tell you exactly how to to get rid of it? Did you try that?

Comment: This is the same as your earlier question; IMO it shouldn't be asked again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [OSX Lion Homebrew "brew install mysql -v" problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238393/osx-lion-homebrew-brew-install-mysql-v-problems)

Comment: @AndrewMarshall yes, I ran the command.  no dice.  It is not the same as the last question because this is specifically related to Homebrew only.

Comment: @chrishough What does `git status` say when in `/usr/local`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall it says: "nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)"

Comment: @chrishough Edit your question with the entire output please.

Comment: @chrishough Oh wow that should not be like that. You may want to [open an issue with Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/new), you may get better help there `:)`

Comment: @AndrewMarshall darn, I just posted a thread https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11761 over there.  will keep this updated once I have a solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After posting on the homebrew issues log https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11761 I was able to clear the error by running `git clean -df` and once that is finished `brew doctor`. Once complete you should see:

```
Your system is raring to brew.
```

Comment: Just to be explicit because I missed it: run 'git clean -df' command in the /usr/local directory.

Comment: Make sure to do a dry run to double-check what's being cleaned: `git clean -dfn`. Just a friendly reminder that there's no way to undo a git clean.