# brew doctor says I have have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew but git status says "nothing to commit"

Tags: homebrew

I'm installing brew for the first time, and down to one error when I run brew doctor:

```
Warning: You have uncommitted modifications to Homebrew
If this a surprise to you, then you should stash these modifications.
Stashing returns Homebrew to a pristine state but can be undone
should you later need to do so for some reason.
    cd /usr/local && git stash
```

If I cd to /usr/local and run "git status" I get:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

If I run: cd /usr/local && git stash, I get:

```
No local changes to save
```

Should I ignore this warning? I'm on OSX 10.8.

Comment: possible duplicate of [homebrew brew doctor fail message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238786/homebrew-brew-doctor-fail-message)

Comment: This isn't the same as that thread. That user had a lot of changes pending in /usr/local (after running git status). In my case I have no changes pending, but brew doctor still thinks I do. And I've tried the solution from that thread already - git clean -df; that didn't help me because there's nothing to clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem, researching a different problem. My computer had an older version of git installed (1.5.6.56.g29b0d). It was located at /usr/local/bin/git. I downloaded the latest version (1.7.11.3) which installed itself at /usr/local/git/bin/git. After tweaking my PATH to recognize the new git, I was able to get past the error above.

```
brew doctor
Warning: Your Homebrew is outdated
You haven't updated for at least 24 hours, this is a long time in brewland!
```

Then I was able to run brew update successfully:

```
brew update
Updated Homebrew from ed127082 to 4a36c56a.
...
```

And now it looks like I'm good to go:

```
brew doctor
Your system is raring to brew.
```

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue, none of the above suggestions got rid of the warning for me.

It appears that Homebrew will complain about un-committed/un-stashed changes even if they haven't been added to a commit, and if they haven't been added to a commit, git stash won't do anything.

So what i had to do is:

```
$ cd /usr/local
$ git add .    # add the unsaved changes homebrew is complaining about
$ git stash    # stash the changes, now that they're in a commit
$ brew update  # update homebrew
$ brew doctor  # running brew doctor now outputs 'raring to brew'
```

Or if you want, run everything at once:

```
cd /usr/local/Homebrew && git add . && git stash && git clean -d -f && brew update && brew doctor
```